# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch error

Tags: openlayers, osrm

I am trying to implement [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/079xha47/) example on my own server. But it doesn't work properly.When I click to plot points sometimes the icon doesn't appear. Then it gives many errors. Is it about here?

```
var points = [],
    msg_el = document.getElementById('msg'),
    url_osrm_nearest = 'https://router.project-osrm.org/nearest/v1/driving/',
    url_osrm_route = 'https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/',
    icon_url = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/ol3/master/examples/data/icon.png',
    vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector(),
    vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource
    }),
    styles = {
      route: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          width: 6, color: [40, 40, 40, 0.8]
        })
      }),
      icon: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
          anchor: [0.5, 1],
          src: icon_url
        })
      })
    };
```

How can I solve it?